# Properly Discontinuous Action and Covering Spaces

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, covering-spaces

Out of interest, I have been trying my hand at the following problem that is relevant to covering spaces:

Let $X$ be a locally compact and simply connected Riemann surface and let $G$ be a discrete subgroup of the group of automorphisms of $Aut(X)$ (here discrete is taken to mean that the identity element is an isolated point of $G$ within the Lie group $Aut(X)$). If $G$ acts freely on $X$, then the action of $G$ is properly discontinuous, that is, the set
$$\{g \in G \ | \ K \cap g(K) \neq \emptyset\}$$
is finite for every compact subset $K \subset X$.

I have tried a sequence argument to no avail (unless I am missing something crucial) and I have tried searching the many questions relating to properly discontinuous actions that can be found on this site. However, I have yet to find an answer that is specific to this question so I decided to ask it myself. It would be greatly appreciated if I could be pointed in the right direction on this particular problem, or even directed to a highly similar question (specifically with this definition of properly discontinuous) that I have overlooked. Thanks!

**Edit:** It was made apparent to me in the comments that my original question might not end up being true, so I have imposed a further assumption that $X$ is a Riemann surface. If even now my question is not true, I would appreciate seeing either a counter-example or an explanation to how this is false. Thanks again!

Comment: I am not sure this is true. If $X$ is a manifold and $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ is the group of diffeomiorphisms of $X$, then maybe this is true. But if by $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ you simply mean the group of homeomorphisms of $X$, with the compact-open topology, I don't think this would be true...

Comment: I see now that you wrote "within the Lie group $Aut(X)$". But it is not a Lie group - if you mean the group of homeomorphisms. Perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: Well the real problem I came across was specifically to do with Riemann surfaces, so I was hoping that it could be generalised?

Comment: If it is not true in this general setting, then I am perfectly happy to edit my question to include the fact that $X$ is a Riemann surface.

Comment: If $X$ is Riemannian and $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ consists of *isometries* of $X$, then this is true. You can post this as a new question perhaps - this one is interesting, and I'm rather hoping someone will still answer it ;)